# using anonymousAuthentication for Windows AD users

Tags: .net, windows, authentication, iis-7

[anonymousAuthenticaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication) has a username, which defaults to local user [IUSR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis), and a password.
If I understand the docs correctly, the password can by arbitrary. To authenticate with the website, you should use the password, and then the site runs with the permissions of the user specified in username. 
This doesn't make any sense. 
If the username belong to a network user, the site couldn't use it's network credentials without a token, for which it would need a password. 
If the user is local, and different than IUSR, then again the IIS user should be able to do privilege escalation and run with it's credentials.

What am I missing ? And specifically, can anonymousAuth be used to authenticate with Windows accounts? (I know it's an odd usecase, because I can just use WindowsAuthentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If I understand the docs correctly, the password can by arbitrary", that's where misunderstanding comes.

Only a few special accounts like `IUSR` and Active Directory Managed Service Accounts can be configured without passwords, because Windows knows how to query their passwords automatically.

In all other cases, a valid password must be provided by you, or the application will fail with an error page.